# How do I submit multiple forms using ajax and one submit button?

Tags: php, ajax, postgresql

How will I submit multiple forms in ajax using one submit button?

Right now I am using multiple ajax form submits to submit each form individually, but I'm sure there's an easier way to submit the form all at once, and I'm not sure how.

```
$('#submit').click(function(){            
           $.ajax({  
                url:"answer.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_answer').serialize(),  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     location.reload(); 
                     $('#add_answer')[0].reset();

                }  
           });  
      }); 

        $('#submit1').click(function(){            
           $.ajax({  
                url:"answer.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_answer1').serialize(),  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     location.reload();  

                }  
           });  
      }); 

      $('#submit2').click(function(){            
           $.ajax({  
                url:"answer.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_answer2').serialize(),  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     location.reload();  

                }  
           });  
      }); 

      $('#submit3').click(function(){            
           $.ajax({  
                url:"answer.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_answer3').serialize(),  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     location.reload();  

                }  
           });  
      }); 

      $('#submit4').click(function(){            
           $.ajax({  
                url:"answer.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_answer4').serialize(),  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     location.reload();  

                }  
           });  
      }); 

      $('#submit5').click(function(){            
           $.ajax({  
                url:"answer.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_answer5').serialize(),  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     location.reload();  

                }  
           });  
      }); 
 });
```

I also have multiple forms similar to the one below, just with different values.

```
<form name="add_answer5" id="add_answer5">  
                          <div class="table-responsive">  
                               <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field5">  
                                    <tr> 
                                         <label><?php echo $question ?></label>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="answer[]" placeholder="Enter your Answer" value="<?php echo $answer; ?>" class="form-control name_list" /></td> 
                                         <input type="hidden" name="id[]" placeholder="<?php echo $id?>" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="form-control name_list" />                                    
                                         <input type="hidden" name="dg_no[]" placeholder="<?php echo $dg_no;?>" value="<?php echo $dg_no;?>" class="form-control name_list" />
                                         <input type="hidden" name="code_no[]" placeholder="<?php echo $code_no;?>" value="<?php echo $code_no;?>" class="form-control name_list" />
                                         <input type="hidden" name="question[]" placeholder="<?php echo $question;?>" value="<?php echo $question;?>" class="form-control name_list" />

                                    </tr>
                    <?php }?>

                               </table>
                               <button type="button" name="add" id="add5" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button>
                               <input type="button"  class="btn btn-info" id="submit5" value="Submit" />  
                          </div>  
                     </form>
```

So how would I go about submitting the forms all at once? I was thinking something along the lines of placing all the ajax submit into one function, and calling that function when the submit button is clicked, but again I am not sure if that is the correct way to do it.

Comment: create a `FormData` object and populate it with individual objects for each form?

Comment: 1. Question: Why u need ajax here when u already reloading the page in the ajax success. 2. Answer : Create a single form wrap them inside a div with different Id like [add_answer1,add_answer2, etc]. Write a simple script to get all input and pass it to ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As example of what I meant with the comment above ( using a FormData object ) I quickly hashed together a demo to indicate how you might accomplish the stated aim. There is no jQuery, just plain, vanilla Javascript but you could easily (i'm sure ) modify this to use jQuery if you need to.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        ob_clean();

        echo "process the request, send a response, live long & prosper!";

        exit();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>multiple forms: one submit</title>
        <script>
            const submitall=function(e){
                const callback=function(r){
                    console.info( 'response: %o',r )
                }

                const ajax=function(url,data,callback){
                    let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                        if( this.readyState==4 && this.status==200 )callback( xhr.response );
                    };
                    xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
                    xhr.send( data )
                };

                /* add all data from each form to this object */
                let fd=new FormData();

                /* get references to all forms */
                let oCol=document.querySelectorAll( 'form' );

                /* process each form */
                for( let n in oCol ){
                    if( oCol[ n ].nodeType==1 ){
                        let tmp={};
                        for( i in oCol[ n ].elements ){
                            if( typeof( oCol[n][i] )!='undefined' && oCol[n][i].nodeType==1 ){
                                tmp[ oCol[n][i].name ]=oCol[n][i].value;
                            }
                        }
                        fd.append( oCol[n].name, JSON.stringify( tmp ) );
                    }
                }
                ajax.call( this, location.href, fd, callback )
            }

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
                document.getElementById('master').onclick=submitall;
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <input type='button' id='master' value='Gather all & submit' />

        <form name='add_answer1' id='add_answer1'>  
              <div class='table-responsive'>  
                   <table class='table table-bordered' id='dynamic_field1'>  
                        <tr> 
                             <label>question 1</label>
                             <td>
                                <input type='text' name='answer[]' placeholder='Enter your Answer' value='answer 1' class='form-control name_list' />
                                <input type='hidden' name='id[]' placeholder='id' value='id 1' class='form-control name_list' />                                    
                                <input type='hidden' name='dg_no[]' placeholder='dg_no' value='dg_no 1' class='form-control name_list' />
                                <input type='hidden' name='code_no[]' placeholder='code_no' value='code_no 1' class='form-control name_list' />
                                <input type='hidden' name='question[]' placeholder='question' value='question 1' class='form-control name_list' />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                   </table>
                   <button type='button' name='add' id='add1' class='btn btn-success'>Add More</button>
              </div>
        </form>

        <form name='add_answer2' id='add_answer2'>  
              <div class='table-responsive'>  
                   <table class='table table-bordered' id='dynamic_field2'>  
                        <tr> 
                             <label>question 2</label>
                             <td>
                                <input type='text' name='answer[]' placeholder='Enter your Answer' value='answer 2' class='form-control name_list' /> 
                                <input type='hidden' name='id[]' placeholder='id 2' value='id 2' class='form-control name_list' />                                    
                                <input type='hidden' name='dg_no[]' placeholder='dg_no 2' value='dg_no 2' class='form-control name_list' />
                                <input type='hidden' name='code_no[]' placeholder='code_no 2' value='code_no 2' class='form-control name_list' />
                                <input type='hidden' name='question[]' placeholder='question 2' value='question 2' class='form-control name_list' />
                             </td>
                        </tr>
                   </table>
                   <button type='button' name='add' id='add2' class='btn btn-success'>Add More</button>
              </div>
        </form>

        <form name='add_answer3' id='add_answer3'>  
              <div class='table-responsive'>  
                   <table class='table table-bordered' id='dynamic_field3'>  
                        <tr> 
                             <label>question 3</label>
                             <td>
                                 <input type='text' name='answer[]' placeholder='Enter your Answer' value='answer 3' class='form-control name_list' /> 
                                 <input type='hidden' name='id[]' placeholder='id 3' value='id 3' class='form-control name_list' />                                    
                                 <input type='hidden' name='dg_no[]' placeholder='dg_no 3' value='dg_no 3' class='form-control name_list' />
                                 <input type='hidden' name='code_no[]' placeholder='code_no 3' value='code_no 3' class='form-control name_list' />
                                 <input type='hidden' name='question[]' placeholder='question 3' value='question 3' class='form-control name_list' />
                             </td>
                        </tr>
                   </table>
                   <button type='button' name='add' id='add3' class='btn btn-success'>Add More</button>
              </div>
        </form>

        <form name='add_answer4' id='add_answer4'>  
              <div class='table-responsive'>  
                   <table class='table table-bordered' id='dynamic_field4'>  
                        <tr> 
                             <label>question 4</label>
                             <td>
                                 <input type='text' name='answer[]' placeholder='Enter your Answer' value='answer 4' class='form-control name_list' /> 
                                 <input type='hidden' name='id[]' placeholder='id 4' value='id 4' class='form-control name_list' />                                    
                                 <input type='hidden' name='dg_no[]' placeholder='dg_no 4' value='dg_no 4' class='form-control name_list' />
                                 <input type='hidden' name='code_no[]' placeholder='code_no 4' value='code_no 4' class='form-control name_list' />
                                 <input type='hidden' name='question[]' placeholder='question 4' value='question 4' class='form-control name_list' />
                             </td>
                        </tr>
                   </table>
                   <button type='button' name='add' id='add4' class='btn btn-success'>Add More</button>
              </div>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I actually managed to fix my problem just by placing all the other submit forms under one of the submit functions. Thanks for the help anyways!